# implementing search feature Nodejs , searching by values from req.query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hey I implemented limiting , pagination , sorting , filtering , field selection and want to implement search feature , I am using postman **(req.query)** and checking if** req.query has a keyword so search **
but the result is empty object

```
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");
const slugify = require("slugify");
const Product = require("../models/productModel");
const ApiError = require("../utils/apiError");

exports.getAllProducts = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  // 1) filtration
  const queryObj = { ...req.query };
  const excludedFields = ["page", "limit", "sort", "fields"];
  excludedFields.forEach((el) => delete queryObj[el]);
  // 1.1) advanced Filtring
  // {price :{$gte :50} , ratingsAverage:{$lt :4.7}} // query must be executed like that
  // { price: { gte: '20' }, ratingsAverage: { lte: '4.6' } } -> this comes from postman testing
  let queryString = JSON.stringify(queryObj);
  queryString = queryString.replace(
    /\b(gte|gt|lte|lt)\b/g,
    (match) => `$${match}`
  );
  const excutedQuery = JSON.parse(queryString);

  // 2) limiting and pagination
  const page = req.query.page * 1 || 1;
  const limit = req.query.limit * 1 || 20;
  const skip = (page - 1) * limit;

  // Prepare Query for Execution
  let mongooseQuery = Product.find(excutedQuery).skip(skip).limit(limit);



  // 3) sorting
  if (req.query.sort) {
    let sortBy = req.query.sort;
    sortBy = sortBy.split(",").join(" ");
    mongooseQuery = mongooseQuery.sort(sortBy);
  } else {
    // default sorting by time product createdAt
    mongooseQuery = mongooseQuery.sort("-createdAt");
  }

  // 4) Fields Limiting
  if (req.query.fields) {
    let selectedFields = req.query.fields;
    selectedFields = selectedFields.split(",").join(" ");
    mongooseQuery = mongooseQuery.select(selectedFields);
  } else {
    mongooseQuery = mongooseQuery.select("-__v");
  }

  // 5) searching   -> keyword = ------
  // $regex (تحتوي علي)  , $options: "i"  -> get both "Men" and "men" .... capital and not
  if (req.query.keyword) {
    const query = {};
    query.$or = [
      {
        title: { $regex: req.query.keyword, $options: "i" },
      },
      {
        description: { $regex: req.query.keyword, $options: "i" },
      },

      // {
      //   title: { $regex: /req.query.keyword/, $options: "i" },
      // },
      // {
      //   description: { $regex: /req.query.keyword/, $options: "i" },
      // },
    ];

    mongooseQuery = mongooseQuery.find(query);
    console.log(query);
  }

  //Execute prepared Query
  const products = await mongooseQuery;

  res.status(200).json({
    page,
    results: products.length,
    status: "success",
    products,
  });
});
```

{
"page": 1,
"results": 0,
"status": "success",
"products": []
}
here is postman result
and here is the route --> {{eshop}}/products?keyword=great